# The relationship between fisher information and EM algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, statistics, expectation-maximization

What is the relationship between fisher information and EM algorithm? When I read papers about EM algorithm, people sometimes discussed fisher information, and there are algorithms which would combine fisher scoring method and EM algorithm together. However, I couldn't find materials clearly illustrate how fisher information is related to EM algorithm and what role it is playing ?

Could anyone help me understand if there is any connection?

Comment: suggest you post this on mathematics or cross validated. I have added an answer below which I think is right but would benefit from the guys on mathematics or cross validated casting their eyes over it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are connected via the [Cramer-Rao lower bound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%E2%80%93Rao_bound). This gives the minimum possible variance of an unbiased estimator as the reciprocal of the Fisher information.

Also the maximum likelihood estimator for theta converges in distribution to N(theta, 1/(fisher information)).